# Determinant and symmetric function of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, determinant, exterior-algebra

Let $H$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and $T$ a linear operator on it with eigenvalues $\lambda_{i_1},\dots,\lambda_{i_n}$. Let $I$ be the identity operator and $z\in\mathbb{C}$. How does one prove
$$\det(I+zT)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n  z^k \sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_k}\lambda_{i_1}(T)\cdots \lambda_{i_k}(T)$$
The right sight came from the exterior product.

Comment: In the inner sum, shouldn't the product be limited to exactly $n-k$ factors?

Comment: @march I had a mistake. It should be $i_k$ not $i_n$

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense.  The units work out that way. Have you tried using the Hamilton-Cayley theorem?

Comment: @march I am not seeing how to use Hamilton-Cayley

Comment: Hamilton-Cayley was unnecessary. Just need to expand the determinant on the left-hand side and write it in terms of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are allowed to assume that we know that the coefficients of the polynomial are symmetric polynomials of the eigenvalues (taken as distinct), then we can show this.  Writing $z=-1/\lambda$, the right-hand side is
$$
\det(I+zT)
=z^n\det\left(T+\frac{1}{z}I\right)
= \frac{(-1)^n}{\lambda^n}\det(T-\lambda I)
=\frac{(-1)^n}{\lambda^n}(\lambda_1-\lambda)(\lambda_2-\lambda)\cdots(\lambda_n-\lambda)\,,
$$
where $\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $T$, taken as distinct. Then,
\begin{align}
\det(I+zT)
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\lambda^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\lambda^k(-1)^k
e_{n-k}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\lambda^{k-n}(-1)^{k-n}
e_{n-k}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-\lambda)^{-k}
e_{k}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)
\end{align}
where $e_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the $k$'th elementary symmetric polynomial in the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  The symmetric polynomials have the alternative representation
$$
e_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{1\leq j_1<\cdots<j_k\leq n}x_{j_1}\cdots x_{j_k}\,.
$$
Finally, then, putting back $z$, we have
\begin{align}
\det(I+zT)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-\lambda)^{-k}
e_{k}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^nz^k
e_{k}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\,
\end{align}
which is exactly the expression in the OP.

---

To prove that the expansion of the product of $(\lambda_j-\lambda)$'s can be written in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials, probably proof by induction would do it.

Comment: Thank you very much!